# Android Market Screen Shot Questions

Tags: android, google-play

I am about to release my first app in the Android market. [I found this link](http://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/developer/bin/answer.py?&answer=1078870) that shows that Google will accept 2-8 screen shots at different resolutions. The resolutions appear to be the resolutions of popular android phones.

Can we upload 2-8 screen shots at each resolution and depending on which android device the user visits the store with it will show the appropriate size? Or is it 2-8 total. If the latter then would screen shots viewed on a very small phone be shrunk or do they pan? And which resolution should I use for the screen shots?

Thank you kindly for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload 8 images in total. There is no per-device selection: all devices will see all 8 images.

In the latest market the first 2 images are shown side by side, then all the subsequent images are shown 3 images to a row below. You can tap any image and the Market app will zoom into that image.

I'd suggest using the largest images your app supports (in my case it is 480x800, so all my images are that size even though the app will run on larger tablet screens).
2. They allow you to focus